# Grails output directory

Tags: java, grails, batch-file

I want to create war using grails, but by default it creates war file in target directory.
I want to deploy my war into Tomcat.
Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: I use command line to build it

Comment: something like "grails prod war "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file you can specify the war like this:

```
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
```

So make target whatever you want.  Although, I'd not recommend WAR'ing directly into Tomcat for deployments.  Unless you are just doing this for local testing.

Comment: I am new in grails, what is build config?

Comment: The `BuildConfig.groovy` file in your `grails-app/conf` directory.